# exception:"Swift Dependency Exception" message : "Cannot lookup dependency \"message.message\" since it is not registered."

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-ses

I am doing this in php with Laravel but I get the following error:

```
Mail::send('contactus.contact_email',
        array(
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'phone_no' => $request->get('phone_no'),
            'user_message' => $request->get('user_message'),
        ), function($message) use ($request)
        {
            $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'));
            $message->to($request->email);
        });
```

Error:

```
exception:"Swift Dependency Exception" message : "Cannot lookup dependency \"message.message\" since it is not registered."
```

I already configure mail.php but i cant send mails

```
Mail::send('contactus.contact_email',
        array(
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'subject' => $request->get('subject'),
            'phone_no' => $request->get('phone_no'),
            'user_message' => $request->get('user_message'),
        ), function($message) use ($request)
        {
            $message->from(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'));
            $message->to($request->email);
        });
```

But the mails is not sended